# Routable Modals Angular issue with wild card redirect Angular 8

Tags: angular, routes, bootstrap-modal

I have a Routable Modal that is used with parameters to display Trainings

in app-routing.module.ts

```
{ path : 'TopshelfContent/:catName/:cmsID', component: ModalContainerComponent, canActivate: [MsalGuard]},
```

If i manually go to the url exmaple /TopshelfContent/Cars/1
if that content exists from api the modal will open automatically and display the content
and if it does not exist it will redirect to dashboard.
This only works if i disable the  '**' wildcard route;

THE ISSUE : If enable

```
{ path :  '**', redirectTo: 'Dashboard', canActivate: [MsalGuard]},
```

and try to manually go to example /TopshelfContent/Cars/1
it redirects to the dashboard. I can't figure out why it thinks the url with the route parameters does not exist.  Any Ideas?

1. top-shelf-detail.component.html where the modal content is poupulated :

   ```
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div  class="col" *ngFor="let videoTrainging of videoTraingings">
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item"
                        [src]="videoTrainging.contentURL | safe" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   ```
2. top-shelf-detail.component.ts  parameters used to subscribe to videoTrainings

   ```
     import { Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
     import { categoriesService } from '../../../Shared/Services/categories.service';
     import { CMSService } from '../../../Shared/Services/cms.service';
     import { AdministrationService  } from '../../../Shared/Services/administration.service';
     import { MsalService } from '@azure/msal-angular';
     import { Router, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
     import { NGXLogger } from 'ngx-logger';

     @Component({
      selector: 'app-top-shelf-detail',
      templateUrl: './top-shelf-detail.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./top-shelf-detail.component.css']
     })
     export class TopShelfDetailComponent implements OnInit {
     @Input() catName;
     @Input() cmsID;

    buNameSelected: any;
    contentTitle: any;
    error: any;
    paramID: any;
    videoTraingings: any;

   constructor(public AdministrationService: AdministrationService, 
    private msalService: MsalService,  public cmsService: CMSService, private logger: NGXLogger,
    public categoriesService: categoriesService, private router: Router, private activatedRoute: 
    ActivatedRoute) { }


    ngOnInit(){
      this.logger.log("catName : " + this.catName + '\n' + "cmsID : " + this.cmsID);
      this.getContent();
    }

    getContent()
    {
      this.cmsService.getContentByID(this.cmsID).subscribe(videoData => {
        this.videoTraingings = videoData;
        this.contentTitle = JSON.stringify(this.videoTraingings.contentTitle);
      }, (error) => {
        this.error = JSON.stringify(error);
      });
    }
   ```
3. modal-container-routable-modals.ts

   ```
   import { Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
   import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
   import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
   import { Subject, from } from 'rxjs';
   import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
   import { TopShelfDetailComponent } from '../components/TopShelf/top-shelf-detail/top-shelf- 
    detail.component';
    import { NGXLogger } from 'ngx-logger';

    @Component({
     selector: 'app-modal-container',
     template: ''
    })
   export class ModalContainerComponent implements OnDestroy {
   destroy = new Subject<any>();
   currentDialog = null;

   constructor(
     private modalService: NgbModal,
     route: ActivatedRoute,
     router: Router,
     private logger: NGXLogger
   ) {
     route.params.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy)).subscribe(params => {
        this.logger.log(params);
       // When router navigates on this component is takes the params and opens up the top-shelf- 
         detail modal
       this.currentDialog = this.modalService.open(TopShelfDetailComponent, {size: 'lg', centered: 
       true});
       this.currentDialog.componentInstance.catName = params.catName;
       this.currentDialog.componentInstance.cmsID = params.cmsID;
       // Go back to home page after the modal is closed
       this.currentDialog.result.then(result => {
         router.navigateByUrl('/');
       }, reason => {
          router.navigateByUrl('Dashboard');
          this.currentDialog.close();
       });
    });
   }
    ngOnDestroy()
    {
      this.destroy.next();
    }
   }
   ```
4. app-routing.module.ts

   ```
     import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
     import { DashboardComponent } from 
     './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
     import { GuideComponent } from './components/guide/guide.component';
     import { MsalModule, MsalGuard } from '@azure/msal-angular';
     import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
     import { OneOnOneComponent } from './components/one-on-one/one-on- 
     one.component';
     import { QuickstartOneComponent } from 
     './components/QuickStartOne/quick-start-one.component';
     import { QuickStartTelstratComponent } from 
     './components/QuickStartTelstrat/quick-start-telstrat.component';
     import { ReportingComponent } from 
     './components/reporting/reporting.component';
     import { ReleasesComponent } from 
     './components/releases/releases.component';
     import { TelstratComponent } from 
     './components/telstrat/telstrat.component';
     import { TelstratGuideComponent } from './components/telstrat- 
     guide/telstrat-guide.component';
     import { TopShelfDashComponent } from './components/TopShelf/topshelf- 
     dash/top-shelf-dash.component';
     import { CmsComponent } from './components/TopShelf/cms/cms.component';
     import { BusinessUnitComponent } from './components/TopShelf/business- 
     unit/business-unit.component';
     import { SettingsComponent } from 
      './components/settings/settings.component';
      import { ModalContainerComponent } from './Shared/modal-container- 
      routable-modals';

     const routes: Routes = [
         { path : 'Dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: 
           [MsalGuard]},
         { path : 'Guide', component: GuideComponent, canActivate: 
           [MsalGuard]},
         { path : 'OneOnOne', component: OneOnOneComponent, canActivate: 
           [MsalGuard]},
         { path : 'QuickstartOne', component: QuickstartOneComponent, 
                canActivate: [MsalGuard]},
         { path : 'QuickstartTelstrat', component: 
                   QuickStartTelstratComponent, canActivate: [MsalGuard]},
         { path : 'Releases', component: ReleasesComponent, canActivate: 
            [MsalGuard]},
         { path : 'Reporting', component: ReportingComponent, canActivate: 
           [MsalGuard]},
         { path : 'BusinessUnit', component: BusinessUnitComponent, 
                canActivate: [MsalGuard]},
         { path : 'Settings', component: SettingsComponent, canActivate: 
           [MsalGuard]},
         { path : 'Telstrat', component: TelstratComponent, canActivate: 
           [MsalGuard]},
         { path : 'TelstratApplicationQuickstart', component: 
           TelstratGuideComponent, canActivate: [MsalGuard]},
         { path : 'TopShelfDashboard', component: TopShelfDashComponent, 
           canActivate: [MsalGuard]},
         { path : 'CMS', component: CmsComponent, canActivate: [MsalGuard]},
             //{ path :  '**', redirectTo: 'Dashboard', canActivate: 
                 [MsalGuard]},
         { path: '', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: 
          [MsalGuard]},
         { path : 'TopshelfContent/:catName/:cmsID', component: 
               ModalContainerComponent, canActivate: [MsalGuard]},
         ];

        @NgModule({
          imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
            //onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'
          })],
          exports: [RouterModule]
         })
        export class AppRoutingModule { }
         export const routingComponents =
   ```

   [DashboardComponent,OneOnOneComponent,QuickstartOneComponent,QuickStartTelstratComponent,
   CmsComponent,ReleasesComponent,ReportingComponent,SettingsComponent,TelstratComponent,TelstratGuideComponent, BusinessUnitComponent, ModalContainerComponent]

Answer (score 0):

When two routes conflict, the order in which you specify the path matters. For your example,
both `TopshelfContent/:catName/:cmsID` and `**` matches, but since you specified the path with wildcard `**` first you are  getting redirected to `Dashboard`. Move the path with wildcard `**` at the end. As a basic rule, always try to order by most specific to least specific.